# Unsupported Media Type, Http error 415

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm actually working on a project which involves an Adobe Flash Player Windows with some Flex which call a rest service contained in a spring mvc controller whose purpose is to use a service generating a pdf file with Jasper report.

Here is the ActionScript method calling the web service:

```
private function editerCourrier():void{

//Security.loadPolicyFile("http://appserv01.siege.xm:4040/Editions/RetardLivraison/crossdomain.xml");
if(this.gridActivated == "mailing"){
    var request:URLRequest = new 

URLRequest("http://10.102.22.143:8280/edition_sc_retards_livraisons/Export/RetardLivraisonLettre");
        var hdr:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.requestHeaders.push(hdr);
        var jsonArray:Array = new Array();
        jsonArray.push({
            "civilite" : "Mr.",
            "destNom" : "TAMBE",
            "destPrenom" : "JOEL",
            "destAdresseFull" : "54 rue des Cocotiers",
            "destCP" : "93270",
            "destVille" : "ANTONY",
            "nomPays" : "FRANCE",
            "pjPath" : "http://192.168.200.97/intranet/e107_files/mail_attachement/MAIL_AVENANT_TEMPORAIRE_1507817106_1534679.txt"
        });
        request.data = jsonArray;
        navigateToURL(request,"win_cour");
    }
}
```

Also, here is the rest controller

```
@Api
@Controller
public class RetardLivraisonLettreControllerImpl implements RetardLivraisonLettreController {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RetardLivraisonLettreControllerImpl.class);

    private final EditionConfig editionConfig;

    private final EditionService editionService;

    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    private static final String ERROR = "error";

    public RetardLivraisonLettreControllerImpl(EditionConfig editionConfig, EditionService editionService) {
        this.editionConfig = editionConfig;
        this.editionService = editionService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Export/RetardLivraisonLettre", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/pdf", consumes = {
            "application/json",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1" }, headers = "Accept=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> retardLivraisonLettre(@RequestBody RetardLivraisonLettreBean bean,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws InvalidParameterException {

        logger.debug("appel retardLivraisonLettre");

        String nomCible = editionConfig.getNomCible();

        try {
            // Download du PDF
            logger.debug("Download du PDF");

            editionService.retardLivraisonLettre(bean, response.getOutputStream());

            response.setContentType("application/x-download");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nomCible);
            response.getWriter().close();
            response.setHeader(SUCCESS, "Edition du PDF de la lettre de retard de livraison effectué avec succès");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            response.setHeader(ERROR, "Erreur lors de l'édition du PDF de la lettre de retard de livraison effectué");
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(response.getHeader(ERROR), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(response.getHeader(SUCCESS), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question because my button now triggers a new the open of a new tab. But I got an http 415 error. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request header should be named "Content-Type", not "Content-type".